# Ways of Indicating Sarcasm in Writing?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Sarcasm is in most cases conveyed by tone of voice or body language, so is much easier to use face-to-face. What are ways of using it in written form?

One way I know of is to use a word that directly suggests sarcasm in context, such as 'totally'.

For example:

> That's **totally** how you are meant to drive a car

Are there other words or methods that achieve this effect? Are any clearer than others?

Comment: I would say the _italics_ makes it more sarcastic. As does "double quotes" - He is such a "genius". That is so _thoughtful_ of you

Comment: [SarcMark?](http://www.sarcmark.com/)

Comment: Wait—it's possible to write sarcastically?

Comment: In the yesteryear of (bad) standup comics, they would employ a drummer to do a [rimshot](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rimshot) to emphasize a joke.  You can do that when posting online by following a "humorous" statement that people may not recognize as humor with a smiley face.  That doesn't work with formal writing, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Almost* all words can convey sarcasm, but the trick is in *how* you use them. Apart from *italics* and "quotes", a standard way of conveying sarcasm is the *hyperbole*, meaning that you very clearly *overstate* something - in case of sarcasm, to mean the opposite.

Be very aware that sarcasm is one of the most difficult emotions to convey in written (on-line) form - I see examples on a daily basis where sarcasm is not picked up by people on discussion forums and the like, which can lead to sometimes very annoying, weird or unpleasant situations.
When in doubt, *overdo* it :

> In this case, Layla accidentally made a mistake.
>   **Yeah, that is a *really* smart thing to do, *genius*! Why didn't *I* think of that?**

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing to persuade, you can make a very clear sarcastic remark by arguing briefly for the extreme opposite. This will confuse the reader long enough for them to realize it's intended as sarcasm. For example, arguing against investment in a hypothetical country's infrastructure:

Many folks in this council are suggesting that we invest in our infrastructure but this will take away from our education budget.

Another reason we should not invest in better infrastructure is because our unemployment rate is the lowest in the world and we are in such a desperate need to provide jobs. We have too many teachers and not enough construction workers; teachers work best with class sizes of more than 200.

Answer (score 0):

*yeah, right*

> Me? Handsome? *Yeahhh, riiight...*